# Confused on percent difference calculations in R using dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm attempting to find the percent differences of state characteristics (using a defined index created using factor analysis) between the years 2012 and 2017. However some states begin with a score of -0.617 (2012) and end with -1.25 (2017), creating a positive percent difference rather than a negative.

The only other thing I've tried is subtracting 1 from the fraction factor1/lag(factor1). Below is is the code I'm currently working with:

```
STFACTOR %>>%
  dplyr::select(FIPSst, Geography, Year, factor1) %>>%
  filter(Year == c(2012, 2017)) %>>%
  group_by(Geography) %>>% 
  mutate(pct_change = (factor1/lag(factor1)-1) * 100)
```

These are the changes and results from each change in code

```
mutate(pct_change = (1-factor1/lag(factor1)) * 100)

  FIPSst Geography   Year factor1[,1] pct_change
  <chr>  <fct>      <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 01     Alabama     2012      1.82         NA  
2 01     Alabama     2017      0.945        47.9
3 04     Arizona     2012      0.813        NA  
4 04     Arizona     2017      0.108        86.7
5 05     Arkansas    2012      1.52         NA  
6 05     Arkansas    2017      0.626        58.8
7 06     California  2012      1.04         NA  
8 06     California  2017      0.0828       92.1
9 08     Colorado    2012     -0.617        NA  
10 08     Colorado    2017     -1.25       -102. 

mutate(pct_change = (factor1/lag(factor1)-1) * 100)

  FIPSst Geography   Year factor1[,1] pct_change   
  <chr>  <fct>      <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 01     Alabama     2012      1.82         NA  
2 01     Alabama     2017      0.945       -47.9
3 04     Arizona     2012      0.813        NA  
4 04     Arizona     2017      0.108       -86.7
5 05     Arkansas    2012      1.52         NA  
6 05     Arkansas    2017      0.626       -58.8
7 06     California  2012      1.04         NA  
8 06     California  2017      0.0828      -92.1
9 08     Colorado    2012     -0.617        NA  
10 08     Colorado    2017     -1.25        102.
```

I would expect the final result to look like this:

```
  FIPSst Geography   Year factor1[,1] pct_change
  <chr>  <fct>      <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 01     Alabama     2012      1.82         NA  
2 01     Alabama     2017      0.945       -47.9
3 04     Arizona     2012      0.813        NA  
4 04     Arizona     2017      0.108       -86.7
5 05     Arkansas    2012      1.52         NA  
6 05     Arkansas    2017      0.626       -58.8
7 06     California  2012      1.04         NA  
8 06     California  2017      0.0828      -92.1
9 08     Colorado    2012     -0.617        NA  
10 08     Colorado    2017     -1.25        -102.
```

Comment: Your `filter` statement is not correct `filter(Year == c(2012, 2017))` should be `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: Please provide a sample of the starting data set with `dput(head(df,n))` for better reproducibility.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it did not change the results. Any ideas to the problem at hand?

Comment: You may need `abs(factor1)/lag(abs(factor1))`

Comment: No luck with that

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with fake data. `factor1[,1]` suggests `factor1` is a matrix, not an atomic vector. Furthermore, the code in the question has 3 occurrences of `%>>%`.

Comment: Try `mutate(pct_change =(factor1 - lag(factor1))/abs(lag(factor1)) * 100)`

Comment: Figured out the same solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
mutate(pct_change = (factor1-lag(factor1))/lag(abs(factor1)) * 100)
```

Above is the final solution to the problem, subtracted the old number from the new before I divided by the absolute value of the old number.

Answer (score 0):

we can use

```
mutate(pct_change =(factor1 - lag(factor1))/abs(lag(factor1)) * 100)
```